# How to find perpendicular point at given distance in ThreeJs

Tags: math, three.js

I have pointA and pointB in world coordinates. I want to find the pointC which will be perpendicular to line AB.

[image]

[image]

Due to my average math skills, I don't know how to find pointC. I searched on google and found that I have to find yaw, pitch and using some formula I can find the pointC at given distance. I followed the solution given in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58469297/how-do-i-calculate-the-yaw-pitch-and-roll-of-a-point-in-3d/58469298#58469298) but still not able to achieve what I want.

I have started learning threejs couple of weeks back and I know we can rotate object using `lookAt()` method. So once I know pointC, I will use the `lookAt()` method to rotate an object.

I am also new in threejs and also tried using `angleTo()` and `axisRotationOnAxis()` but due to lack of knowledge I failed.

Any help?

Comment: Please define "the point C which is perpendicular to line AB". Points are not the sort of thing which is perpendicular to a line. Lines are perpendicular to lines. From your picture it seems that you want C to lie on the perpendicular bisector of the line segment AB -- but there are infinitely points on that bisector. Which one should be picked?

Comment: How would you know where along the AB line will that perpendicular line touch? It looks like it could be anywhere in between.

Comment: @JohnColeman Yes, my bad for that. Point C lies on the perpendicular bisector of the line. What if, I find the centre of the line and find the point c which lies on a perpendicular bisector with distance x? Is it achievable?

Comment: There are two points on the line at distance `x`. Which one do you want?

Comment: @JohnColeman Both the points if possible otherwise point which will help me to rotate the object towards the up direction.

Comment: If you mean 3D (yaw, pitch were mentioned), there is infinite number of points at given distance (they lie on circle)

Comment: Maybe it would help if you said what you were planning to do with this information?

Comment: @JasonSmith Read the docs: https://threejs.org/docs/index.html?q=line3#api/en/math/Line3.closestPointToPoint